# Retrieve iASP RDB name to specify it in jdbc url

Tags: java, jdbc, ibm-midrange

I have a java application which runs on IBM i. It creates connection to AS400 database using jdbc. It does not specify the database name in JDBC connection URL, means it creates connection to default system database associated with *SYSBAS.

Now I want my application to run on iASP. When running on iASP it fails to connect to database.

IBM i documentation says that we must specify RDB name in "database name" property of jdbc connection URL to connect.

problem here is that,

IBM i documentation says by default RDB name of iASP group is same as primary iASP device name in iASP group. But it can be assigned different name.

I am able to retrieve iASP group name and iASP device name programmatically using JTOPEN(by calling API QUSROBJD). Which means my application will work in default scenario. But when RDB name is assigned different name then my application may fail. I want to retrieve RDB name associated with iASP.

How can I retrieve correct RDB name for an iASP?

I tried using API QUSRJOBI, but it is returning database name as blank.

Comment: Have you tried this? what happens?

Comment: Have you tried using `QSYS2.SYSCATALOGS` to get a list of available databases? It shows the name of the database and the ASP number, and whether the database is available or not.

Comment: This way I need to first create a connection with default system database and then by querying I can get CatalogName for iASP group. 

Then I will create a different connection which will be created with this catalog name information.  And by using this new connection I can access objects in the iASP group. 

This seems a solution but can I avoid making two connection?

Comment: You're making a second connection with the JTOPEN in the first place.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy, Thanks for your response. You can post it as an answer. I am still waiting for more responses. Otherwise I'll mark it as an accepted answer.

Comment: @MichaelS. Yes, I have an AS400 object in my application, which I was using for Jtopen call. My application actually maintains one AS400 object and one jdbc connection object.

Answer (score 3):

There are two types of Auxiliary Storage Pool (ASP) on IBM i: System ASPs and independent ASPs (iASP). On DB2 for i, all libraries in the system ASP are treated as a single database and you can qualify tables with a schema name to access a tables in a specific library. According to the documentation that I found, each new iASP creates a new database, and these can be queried in `QSYS2.SYSCATALOGS`. So you will need a connection to the system database and, from that, you can find the database name and connect to each iASP that you need a connection to. Unfortunately I cannot test this as I do not have an iASP available to me.